# How fast can I learn programming for Windows Phone 8.1?

Tags: 8.1

I am planing to learn Windows phone 8.1 development. But I have a time frame to complete the course by my own. 1 month.

Learning Windows 8.1 means learn c# first.

I have worked in another programming languages. So I have prior knowledge.

I have no knowledge about C#.

So what all should I learn in c#.

Can I exclude topics like WCF, MVC, WPF??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume AppStudio is not enough for you. Therefore I'd recommend learing C# + XAML (aka "Silverlight").
If you know object oriented programming (like Java) you can just go ahead and start with some Windows Phone tutorials, C# code is pretty easy to read.
Check out [Microsoft Virtual Academy](http://www.microsoftvirtualacademy.com/), there are a lot of free video courses to get you started.

Comment: If he is starting from scratch, I wouldn't recommend Silverlight. Microsoft is pushing hard towards Universal Apps (WinRT). This is including a huge hint that this is the way to future proof your investments.

Comment: I added quotes to Silverlight, as I don't mean the instead-of-flash-Silverlight, but the "Silverlight App" Model (opposed to HTML5). I mean it's the same thing for universal apps, just different api subset.

Answer (score 0):

You can start pretty much instantly without any programming background or experience using Microsoft's AppStudio available at https://appstudio.windows.com/en-us

If you want something with more freedom, then you'd have to learn either C# + some WPF, or C++ if you want to go native and do high-performance games (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj681687(v=vs.105).aspx)